# Save nosetests results in custom xml file

Tags: python, xml, unit-testing, nose, nosetests

How do I save nosetests results to a custom xml file located in a specific folder?

My directory structure is:

```
    /MyApp
      /TestSuites
      /Logs
```

My test cases are in a file called tests.py located inside /TestSuites

When I try to run:

```
    nosetests tests.py --xunit-file=../Logs/testlog.xml
```

No xml file is generated.

Comment: Do you need to add the `--with-xunit` option?

Comment: Yes, i figured it out, all I had to do was execute it like this: nosetests tests.py --with-xunit --xunit-file=../Logs/testlog.xml

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, all I had to do was execute it like this:

```
    nosetests tests.py --with-xunit --xunit-file=../Logs/testlog.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, if you enter the following at the command line:

```
$ nosetests --help
```

This give a range of options for nosetests, including the required parameter, i.e:

```
--with-xunit
```